# Moto G - Debugging for Android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

When I open the Android Device chooser it shows a phone. But, instead of the serial number and other details it shows a series of question marks - "????????".

Any suggestions on how I can use the phone for debugging?

Comment: Have you installed the Motorola Devicemanager (for the USB driver)? Also make sure the device unlocked and screen is on. My Moto G is displayed correctly in Eclipse on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks Robert!

The problem was with the selection mode. Apparently MTP doesn't work too well with Ubuntu. When I switched to PTP the USB debugging started working.

Comment: You should mention the used operating system in your next question...

Comment: You should ask, before replying.

Comment: Usually only Windows users don't mention their operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the selection mode.

Apparently MTP doesn't work too well with Ubuntu. When I switched to PTP the USB debugging started working.